# Removing Contour around a certain color

Tags: opencv, contour

So i have a skin color range that I'm using to draw the contours of any skin color my camera sees, i.e, it'll draw contour on the hands or faces etc.

However, the range of color that I am using to draw the contours has a red range of 0-255, so it basically draws contour around everything that is red. The red pixel is however important for a good skin detection so I can't change that.

So i was wondering how I could tweek my contour code, so that it doesn't draw contour around the color red.

My code is as follow:

```
min_YCrCb = np.array([0,133,77],np.uint8) # Create a lower bound for the skin color
max_YCrCb = np.array([255,173,127],np.uint8) # Create an upper bound for skin color
skinRegion = cv2.inRange(converted,min_YCrCb,max_YCrCb) # Create a mask with boundaries
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(skinRegion, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # Find the contour on the skin detection
    for i, c in enumerate(contours): # Draw the contour on the source frame
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area > 10000:
            cv2.drawContours(img, contours, i, (255, 255, 0), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with OpenCV, and what many other would recommend, would be converting your RGB color scheme into HSV.

HSV stands for Hue, Saturation, and Value and is just another way of expressing different colors in the white light spectrum. In RGB it can be very difficult to find bright or dull colors but this is not the case in the HSV color range.

In the [Python documentation](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) of OpenCV one can see an example of converting BGR to HSV, NOTE: *The H in HSV has a range of 0-179 while the others are 0-255.*

You can switch to HSV by using the function `hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` and then having your code find the contours within that image stream instead of your original. To figure out what your HSV range should be set to, you can google a RGB to HSV converter [such as this one](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm) - NOTE: *OpenCV commonly uses BGR instead of RBG so be careful not to get them mixed up*

This should help you find the exact range of colors you need to make sure your program is properly working.

```
min_YCrCb = np.array([0,0,0],np.uint8) # Create a lower bound HSV
max_YCrCb = np.array([179,255,255],np.uint8) # Create an upper bound HSV

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(converted, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # assuming converted is your original stream...

skinRegion = cv2.inRange(hsv,min_YCrCb,max_YCrCb) # Create a mask with boundaries
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(skinRegion, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # Find the contour on the skin detection
    for i, c in enumerate(contours): # Draw the contour on the source frame
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area > 10000:
            cv2.drawContours(img, contours, i, (255, 255, 0), 2)
```

Comment: The problem is, the skin color range that I have works really well, and by changing the red range, I'm altering it. So what I need is a way of removing the contours around the red colors, without altering my range, which is what your code is doing

Comment: You are not understanding what my suggestion was, I am saying you need to try using a different color space (in this case HSV). This will allow you to find a range that can show off human skin, but not show off red objects in the same area, this is the easiest and simplest way I can think of helping you as you only have to add one line of code to your program

Comment: well i could use a different color space, but i would use the same range, except converted to HSV. so the red detected in the yrcbr will also be detected in the HSV won't it?

Comment: I believe that if you tuned your HSV properly it should work much better than RGB. Please a screenshot of what the shade of red you don't want is, as to let us know what you want to filter out. You should also try using HSV as it does not take that long at all to tune. Start with H that is the most important and then start working on S and V. I can help more if I can see what red you don't want